# Passing value to JS with php return?

Tags: php, json

I have a php method that should return some values as JSON :

```
function pass_value() {
 .... 
 $output[] = 'some value';
 ...

 if() { 
  //JS get it right
  echo json_encode(array('response' => $output));
  return;
 }
 ...
 //eventually another echo 

}
```

Where's the problem to do it like this ?

```
function pass_value() {
 .... 
 $output[] = 'some value';
 ...

 //js doesn't get it ?
 return json_encode(array('response' => $output)); 
}
```

I want to terminate the other part of the method after it passes the array, but seems that JS doesn't get the JSON when it's not echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because if you do not echo, the server never sends it to the client and the JavaScript never sees it. Remember, PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side.

You can of course do this with the last function:

```
echo pass_value();
```

Comment: So my original solution appears to be fine ? Echoing sequenced by return statement ?

Comment: @Borislav yes. But you can try that out for yourself and find out.